# AWS AMI : Get list of Available Instance Types for specific AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fog, amazon-ami, instancetype

Is there an AWS API method(or fog method) using which I can retrieve the list of instance types that are enabled for an AMI? 
for example:
  I want to get a list of available instance types for AMI ID "ami-716e6534". 
  It should give me list of available types (t1.micro, m1.small,m1.medium...) out of all available types.

Comment: +1...I was not able to find it too... I Hard coded in the end cause i was just using specific AMI's